# React Native Modal + translucent not working on android

Tags: react-native

I want make full screen modal with translucent StatusBar
So, I made Modal with StatusBar.
it work well on ios simulator. but It is just below StatusBar on android, Not full screen

This is my code

```
<Modal>
  <View>
    <StatusBar
      barStyle="dark-content"
      translucent
      backgroundColor="transparent"/>
    <SomeComponent
     ...
    />
  </View>
</Modal>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Any solution for this??